# Debian. How can I securely get debian-archive-keyring, so that I can do an apt-get update? NO_PUBKEY

Tags: debian, apt, public-key

I have a catch 22 trying to:

```
   # apt-get update
   [... good lines omitted]
   W: GPG error: http://backports.debian.org lenny-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
   W: GPG error: http://http.us.debian.org stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
   W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY AED4B06F473041FA
```

At http://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt#Other_problems it notes the NO_PUBKEY issue "means the archive has begun to be signed by a new key, which your system does not know about ...  and once the system is fed the new key (by upgrading the debian-archive-keyring package), the warning will go away"

OK, but perversely:

```
   apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

gives me:

```
   WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
       debian-archive-keyring
```

and the solution for that is to do an **apt-get update**

Can anyone break the cycle for me?

--

Note: my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
    deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ lenny main contrib non-free
    deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
    deb http://security.debian.org lenny/updates main contrib non-free
    deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
```

Comment: If you want to stick with lenny, then you should replace `stable` with `lenny` on the `http.us.debian.org`.  Your current sources.list is probably going to result in a broken system.  If you want to upgrade to squeeze, then you should replace all the `stable/lenny` references, and use `squeeze`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can anyone break the cycle for me?

You are basically just experiencing the standard [bootstrapping problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_%28cryptographic%29) for [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_cryptography).

There are many places you can download the public keys for the various archives, but frequently they are not provided over HTTPS, and any checksum files are delivered from the same location.

That wiki link you provided links off to https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html which has provides a copy of the keys you can download over SSL.  The problem of course is that the cert for ftp-master.debian.org is signed by ca.debian.org, which is not distributed with the most common web browsers.

You basically just have to find a way to get a copy of debian-archive-keyring, or the current key from system that you trust, and the install it onto your system.  If you are really paranoid, you might have to grab a copy of the archive, and have someone else grab a copy from another mirror on a different computer over a different network.  Then compare the checksums.

If you are not extremely paranoid, or in a high security environment, then just let `apt-get install debian-archive-keyring` install, and ignore the warning.

It would take a lot of effort for someone to setup a MITM between you and the some random http.us.debian.org mirror.  Once they did that, they would have to build their own custom debian-archive-keyring package including their evil key in addition to the standard keys.  Then they would have to rebuild some packages to force you to install something evil onto your system.  The effort involved would not be trivial.

Debian generally does a pretty good job adding keys that will be used to sign the packages in the future to the debian-archive-keyring package.  That is one package, that you really want to keep up-to-date.  That way, you will key the keys installed before they are used for signing things, and you won't have this problem in the future.

Comment: Yeah, Chrome gave me a big fat alert on account of the SSL cert signer not being trusted.  Sigh.

Comment: PS.FYI.  The current fingerprint I have for the squeeze signing key is `0E4E DE2C 7F3E 1FC0 D033 800E 6448 1591 B983 21F9` and lenny is `7F5A 4445 4C72 4A65 CBCD 4FB1 4D27 0D06 F425 84E6`.

Comment: Well, my hypothetical enemies are influential, so it's no big deal that the SSL certificate for ftp-master.debian.org is not signed by one of the compromised CA's that my browser trusts out of the box.  So I got Moxie Marlinspike's Convergence plugin for Firefox.  At least I think I did - he didn't trouble to sign the add-on I installed, and it crashed Firefox when I installed it.  I have no idea if the default notary servers are reliable, but they seem to agree that the key website is the same one I'm looking at. But probably my enemies already compromised Debian.  So heck, I'm going with it.

Comment: Thanks for the fingerprint.  Somehow, rightly or wrongly, I trust someone who gives up their time to help a stranger.

Comment: Aaaaugh, can anybody provide me with a link to a secure place to download Debian CD signing keys?  I am extremely paranoid.  Also annoyed, since you'd think they'd AT LEAST use SSL on the page they gave you the keys, if you're gonna be bothering to check them at all.

Comment: You could get them from the mit pgp key database, if you don't like like grabbing them off the archives.  `http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/pks/lookup?search=Wheezy+Stable+Release+Key&op=index`

Answer (score 14):

Your problem is that you didn't install debian-keyring as well. Simply run the following:

```
apt-get install debian-keyring
apt-get install debian-archive-keyring
```

That's it.

Comment: I can confirm this works

Comment: `debian-keyring` has [nothing to do](https://serverfault.com/a/960837/162443) with installing packages.

Answer (score 5):

[Debian - Apt-get : NO_PUBKEY / GPG error](http://ccm.net/faq/809-debian-apt-get-no-pubkey-gpg-error)

In computers based on a Debian operating system that uses Linux kernel, error messages may come up like 'NO_PUBKEY'.This happens while using the Apt-Get command line tool and this error is associated with the tool's update feature. The new feature in the Apt-Get package management tool guarantees the authenticity of the server before updating the Debian OS. That's why the error 'NO_PUBKEY' pops up. This problem can be solved by keying in the appropriate commands.

Simply type the following commands, taking care to replace the number below with that of the key that was displayed in the error message:

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  AED4B06F473041FA      
gpg -a --export AED4B06F473041FA | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: I have experimented above solution and this worked for me. Solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1. Your sources.list file may be incorrect; are you sure those are the right lines for those repos?
2. You'll have to manually locate the Release.gpg files on those repos and update the keyring:

`wget -q http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/dists/squeeze-backports/Release.gpg -O -|apt-key add -`

You might be playing with fire by mixing lenny with the stable repo

Comment: I'm not sure about #1.  I was following instructions at http://www.spinifex.com.au/plugs/dphowtos.html#debian but the line "deb http://www.backports.org/debian lenny-backports main contrib non-free" was giving download errors, so blindly following http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/ I changed it to "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main".  Now I have it as "deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free" ... is that better ? (I hate playing with fire).  Still get 'NO_PUBKEY' tho, so will do your #2.

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-key adv --keyserver subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys YOUR_KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

The right thing to do is to not worry about getting the key to your machine securely, but being able to accurately check your trust path to the key once you have it on your machine.  This means that you want to find a chain of signatures where your gpg key was used to sign someone's key that was used to sign someone's key... so that you eventually find someone that signed the archive key.

This would obviously be tedious if you were to try to do this by hand if you are more than a couple of steps away from the key.  wotsap is a package which will help you discover paths from your key to the keys of the people that have directly signed the archive key.

This all is predicated on you having a gpg key and participating in gpg keysigning, which is absolutely essential if you want to really do this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone run on this one trying to build a Dockerfile based on stretch :

```
# debian stretch moved to archive.debian.org on 2023-03-27
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" && \
    echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main non-free contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get update -o Acquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true -o Acquire::AllowDowngradeToInsecureRepositories=true -o APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated=true && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends -o APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated=true debian-archive-keyring
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got no key because your debian-archive-keyring is too old, you can securely upgrade it by adding an earlier release of Debian to [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList), and installing a new keyring signed by the old key. You might need to do this if your install was [Debian "testing"](https://www.debian.org/devel/testing).

I had an install of Debian 10 "buster" from 2018, when it was "testing", and before it released in 2019. I needed to upgrade it in 2022, but I was missing buster's release key. I followed these steps.

1. Run `apt-key list` to look for keys. I had the key for Debian 9 "stretch", the next key before "buster" in [Debian's Archive Signing Keys](https://ftp-master.debian.org/keys.html).
2. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add stretch. (I had lines for stretch, so I uncommented them. It would also work to copy buster's lines and change buster to stretch.)
3. Run `apt update` to scan stretch's sources.
4. Run `apt-get install debian-archive-keyring/stretch` to install stretch's keyring. It said that my package "will be DOWNGRADED". I said "Y", downgrading it from 2017.7 to 2017.5+deb9u1, because 2017.5+deb9u1 has buster's key.
5. Run `apt update` to scan buster's sources. It said that buster "changed its Version value from '' to '10.13'" and "its 'Suite' value from 'testing' to 'oldstable'". I said "Y".
6. Run `apt upgrade` as usual.