# Difference between debian-keyring and debian-archive-keyring?

Tags: debian, apt, debian-archive-keyring

Do I need both to install packages? What is the purpose of each of those?

Comment: @anx I've got a Debian Squeeze server. Unfortunately, I can't upgrade in the near future. So I was trying to make it work with Debian Archive. But had issues with gpg keys. The solution is most likely to just update `debian-archive-keyring`, but [some people](https://serverfault.com/a/385890/162443) say `debian-keyring` is to be updated as well. That's what led me to asking the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`debian-archive-keyring` is **the *minimal* collection of keys** used for Debian Release files, it provides the keys that are used when signing stable releases and (security) updates.

This NNN-kilobyte-sized collection is sufficient to verify the officially signed archives.
**This package is important if you use Debian (or at least part of its package archives) yourself.**

**This package installs keys into the apt trust database and therefore directly impacts package installation.** More information on how the security of apt works can be found in [man 8 apt-secure](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-secure.8.en.html)

If your system is not Debian, but you are using it to install Debian (e.g via *debootstrap*), this package is helpful, as you can use the keys to verify packages from insecure media or connections.

---

`debian-keyring` is **a *much larger* collection of keys** providing the keys of all Debian Developers, Maintainers, and some more role (non-personal) keys.
This NN-megabyte-sized collection is sufficient to verify that an individual package announcement was signed by someone who was at some point a Debian Developer or Maintainer.

**This package does not change the apt trust db and therefore has no direct impact on package installation. It is meant to be configured manually to verify signatures.**

A typical example for such signature can be found in the *Debian source control files* for the [package debian-keyring](https://packages.debian.org/sid/debian-keyring) itself. The file `debian-keyring_2019.03.24.dsc` identifies the sources for version 2019.03.24 of that package. The file is signed by *Jonathan McDowell*, a long-standing Debian Developer. His key is part of the collection that package provides.

If you are not working with such files (if you are not testing or developing Debian Packages), **this package is probably not useful to you**.
And even if you did, this package is only for your convenience, as the actual authoritative source for the data contained therein is the [Debian Public Key Server](https://keyring.debian.org/).

Comment: So, basically each version of every package is signed with a key from `debian-keyring`, and it is not verified when installing a package. What is verified is the signature on a Release file of a repository.